# How to use reset Button effectively in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Reset button is not working in this code given below.

```
<head>
<title><b>Title of project<b/></title>
</head><br/>
<body bgcolor="skyblue"><br/>
<p>
<b><h2><center>Enter Details:</center></h2></b><br/>
<center><br/>
First Name:<input type="text" name="name"><hr/><br/>
Last Name:<input type="text" name="name"><hr/><br/>
mail-id:<input type="text" name="mail"><hr/><br/>
</center><br/>

<form method="link" action="view1.html"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="login">login<br/>
<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button><br/>
</form><br/>
</p><br/>
</body><br/>
```

Comment: `bgcolor` - Obsolete, `<center>` - Obsolete. You - Old person! `:P`

Comment: Your form should enclose all elements for reset button to work...code below

Comment: @PraveenKumar It's called "obsolete" now. "deprecated" is old! Also, you forget to mention the errors: `h2` in `b`, stray `</p>` end tag for a paragraph that was closed long ago, `<br/>` after the body etc.

Comment: i think this question should be close as it is totally low level and will create spam rather then help someone.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Well, you did mention the duplicate name attribute in your answer, so why not be complete about it. There's also the `<b>` in the title, the mismatch between self-closing and not-self-closing tags, the non-standard `method` in the form, etc.

Comment: Copy this and edit your code.you will get the expected output.   After center tag enter form method tag as given below.                                                                                                                                                                               <center><form method="link" action="view1.html">

Answer (score 4):

The `reset` doesn't work because, your `<form>` **does not contain** the `<input />`s.  Please include the `<input />` tags inside the `<form>` tag. Change the code to:

```
<form method="link" action="view1.html"><br/>
<center><br/>
First Name:<input type="text" name="name"><hr/><br/>
Last Name:<input type="text" name="name"><hr/><br/>
mail-id:<input type="text" name="mail"><hr/><br/>
</center><br/>

<input type="submit" value="login">login<br/>
<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button><br/>
</form><br/>
```

Moreover, I suggest you to "upgrade" your code to:

```
<form method="link" action="view1.html">
    <div>First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /></div>
    <div>Last Name:<input type="text" name="lname" /></div>
    <div>mail-id:<input type="text" name="mail" /></div>
    <input type="submit" value="login">login<br/>
    <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Change the `name` attribute to `fname` and `lname`.

**Mistakes in your code:**

1. Do not use `<center>`, `<b>` tags. They are obsolete.
2. Do not use `<br />` tags for layout. They are for content. Use `<div>`s instead.
3. Do not wrap `<h2>` with `<b>`. Wrapping a block element with inline is like containing a bottle inside water, not the other way round.
4. Do not use any content after `</body>`. You have used another break.
5. The `<p>` tag cannot contain anything other than inline elements. Please use `<p>` only for content tags.
6. The `<title>` element cannot contain other HTML elements, only text.
7. The `method` attribute on a `<form>` can only be `"get"` or `"post"`.

Comment: @VinayDuddegere Updated. Can you kindly check.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Nicely done. Hope you don't mind me adding two more errors to your list.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks. `:)`

Comment: Can't we write also that method attribute have 4 type but we can only use get and post and others(put/delete) are usable with ajax(with limited browsers and [supported by the implementations of XMLHttpRequest] ). Just for more knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` tag should enclose all form elements, for reset button to work

```
<form method="link" action="view1.html">
First Name:<input type="text" name="name"><hr/><br/>
Last Name:<input type="text" name="name"><hr/><br/>
mail-id:<input type="text" name="mail"><hr/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="login">login<br/>
<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button><br/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

A reset button only resets the inputs in the form it's in.

Solution: put the inputs in the form as well. This will also solve the other problem, namely that the submit button doesn't submit the input values.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of project</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="skyblue">
<p>
<h2><center>Enter Details:</center></h2>
<center><br/>
<form method="link" action="view1.html">
First Name:<input type="text" name="name"><hr/>
Last Name:<input type="text" name="name"><hr/>
mail-id:<input type="text" name="mail"><hr/>
</center><br/>

<input type="submit" value="login">
<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
</form>
</p>
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Man... Add some details to your post. Don't post just a simple answer, which doesn't say anything, what you changed or stuff.